# Angular 7 Websocket handle Subject<MessageEvent>

Tags: angular, websocket, message

I am trying to implement a very simple WebSockets based Angular application, that I got from an example.
The connection is established like this:

```
public connect(url): Subject<MessageEvent> {
if (!this.subject) {
  this.subject = this.create(url);
  console.log('Successfully connected: ' + url);
}
return this.subject;
```

}

And this is how I am trying to adapt the output from our websocket - but .map does not exist and I have been looking at how to handle Subject and I just cant get a handle on it

```
public messages: Observable<Message>;

constructor(private wsService: WebsocketService) {
        this.messages = wsService.connect(CHAT_URL).map(
          (response: MessageEvent): Message => {
            const data = JSON.parse(response.data);
            return {
              author: data.author,
              message: data.message
            };
          }
        );
    }
```

**EDIT**
I get the following Error:

```
error TS2339: Property 'map' does not exist on type 'Subject<MessageEvent>'.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I hope your method is listening inside ngOnit or the constructor. Try this.

```js
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';

ngOnit() {
this.messages = this.wsService.connect(CHAT_URL).pipe(map(
  (response: MessageEvent): Message => {
    const data = JSON.parse(response.data);
    return {
      author: data.author,
      message: data.message
    };
  }));
}
```

**Note:** try `rxjs/webSocket` too

Comment: ok i should have provided the error straight away **error TS2339: Property 'map' does not exist on type 'Subject<MessageEvent>'**

Comment: this produces two errors: **error TS2322: Type 'Observable<Message>' is not assignable to type 'Subject<Message>'.  Property 'observers' is missing in type 'Observable<Message>'** (i updated the inital code to the variable is visible). and **error TS2552: Cannot find name 'map'. Did you mean 'Map'?** (tsconfig: "target": "es6", "lib": [
 "es6","dom"])

Comment: Did you follow my code above? If you pipe the subject returned from method connect, you'll be able to use map inside. But make sure you have imported it from `rxjs/operators`. Also convert the public message variable to Subject<Message>

Comment: Also return data without mapping it inside.

Comment: I needed to add this.messages = **<Subject<Message>>** this.wsService.connect(